# Tic-Tac-Toe command line

Tags: javascript, node.js, console, tic-tac-toe

I created a simple Tic-Tac-Toe.  I'm looking for any critiques from a code standpoint: general structure / style / efficiency.

Unfortunately I couldn't get a live demo working because of the dependency on the NodeJS library prompt.

```
/*  A simple Tic-Tac-Toe game implemented in Javascript V8 3.14.5.9

Players 'X' and 'O' take turn inputing their position on the command line using numbers 1-9

1 | 2 | 3
---------
4 | 5 | 6
---------
7 | 8 | 9

*/


// prompt for nodejs is required: https://github.com/flatiron/prompt
// npm install prompt
var prompt = require('prompt');

var board = {
    1: ' ',
    2: ' ',
    3: ' ',
    4: ' ',
    5: ' ',
    6: ' ',
    7: ' ',
    8: ' ',
    9: ' '
};

function markBoard(position, mark) {
    board[position] = mark.toUpperCase();
}

function printBoard() {
    console.log('\n' +
        ' ' + board[1] + ' | ' + board[2] + ' | ' + board[3] + '\n' +
        ' ---------\n' +
        ' ' + board[4] + ' | ' + board[5] + ' | ' + board[6] + '\n' +
        ' ---------\n' +
        ' ' + board[7] + ' | ' + board[8] + ' | ' + board[9] + '\n');

}

function isInt(value) {
    var x;
    if (isNaN(value)) {
        return false;
    }
    x = parseFloat(value);
    return (x | 0) === x;
}

function validateMove(position) {
    if (isInt(position) === true && board[position] === ' ') {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// Everyone possible combination of three in a row
var winCombinations = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [1, 4, 7],
                       [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9], [1, 5, 9], [3, 5, 7]];

// Determins if the passed in player has three in a row
function checkWin(player) {
    for (var i = 0; i < winCombinations.length; i++) {
        var markCount = 0;
        for (var j = 0; j < winCombinations[i].length; j++) {
            if (board[winCombinations[i][j]] === player) {
                markCount++;
            }
            if (markCount === 3) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function playTurn(player) {

    console.log('Your turn player: ' + player);
    prompt.start();
    prompt.get(['position'], function (err, result) {

        if (validateMove(result.position) === true) {
            markBoard(result.position, player);
            printBoard();
            if (checkWin(player) === true) {
                console.log('Winner Winner!');
                return;
            }
            if (player === 'X') {
                playTurn('O');
            } else {
                playTurn('X');
            }
        } else {
            console.log('incorrect input please try again...');
            playTurn(player);
        }
    });
}

console.log('Game started: \n' +
    ' 1 | 2 | 3 \n' +
    ' --------- \n' +
    ' 4 | 5 | 6 \n' +
    ' --------- \n' +
    ' 7 | 8 | 9 \n');


playTurn('X');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code was very well organized and was extremely easy to follow along.

---

Looks to me that `board` is just a 1-based array.

It would be easier (and it makes more sense) to use an array, instead of an object.

But don't change how you are asking the user for input. You want to translate the user input one number back, so if the user enters "1" for box number 1, just subtract 1 from the integer version of the input *and then* pass it to `markBoard`.

```
if (validateMove(result.position) === true) {
    markBoard(result.position - 1, player);
    printBoard();
```

---

In your `markBoard` function, there is no point in calling `.toUpperCase` as the `player` variable passed in from `playTurn` is already a capital letter.

---

You are making `validateMove` too complicated. Just do:

```
return isInt(position) && board[position] === ' ';
```

If the expression evaluates to `true`, it will return `true`. If it evaluates to `false`, it will return `false`.

*Note: I omitted the `=== true` because JavaScript automatically checks for something to equal `true`.*

---

It doesn't look like you have anything to check if the user enters an invalid number.

I would add something to the end of `validateMove` to check to make sure that the option is in bounds.

Here is what I came up with:

```
return isInt(position) && board[position] === ' ' && (position >= 0 && position <= 8);
```

It would be >= 1 && <= 9 if you continued to use the object instead of the array for storing squares of the board

---

This might help your efficiency:

Try moving this conditional from `checkWin`

```
if (markCount === 3) {
    return true;
}
```

Outside of the inner `for` loop so you aren't doing a conditional check with each iteration.

---

In `checkWin`, you do a lot of looping. In each loop, you are destroying and re-making variables as they exit and leave the scope (the loop).

This is very optimal. To help this, move the declarations of `markCount`, `i`, and `j` to the very top of the function (before the loops). You can set them to 0 when they are needed.

Here is what I am saying:

```
function checkWin(player) {
    var i, j, markCount
    for (i = 0; i < winCombinations.length; i++) {
        markCount = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < winCombinations[i].length; j++) {
            if (board[winCombinations[i][j]] === player) {
                markCount++;
            }
            if (markCount === 3) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

*Notice how I removed the `var`s?*

---

I'm a little confused by what your `isInt` function is trying to accomplish.

To make it simpler, just run `isNaN` on the position. It will return `NaN` (which acts like `false` in a conditional) if the user entered a string, rather than a number.

Comment: Cheers.  Good stuff. validateMove does check that the option is within bounds but isn't obvious.  If the board position is a space then that position is valid.  (Not already taken and between 1-9)  I think a comment is needed to explain.     The `isInt` function was taken from here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636536/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-an-integer-in-javascript

Comment: For checkWin doesn't JavaScript already hoist var i, j, markCount to the top of the function?

Answer (score 2):

This is great. Your validation can be handled for you by prompt, though, e.g.

```
  const positionQuery = `${player}'s turn. choose a position 1-9`
  const position = {
    properties: {
      [positionQuery]: {
        pattern: /^[1-9]{1}$/,
        message: 'Choose a position 1-9',
        required: true
      }
    }
  }
  prompt.start()
  prompt.get([positionQuery], (err, result) => {
   ...
  }
```